I solved a problem but I'm not sure where I am wrong. - game of craps
I'm a student studying probability and got a problem while solving the following:
The game of craps is played as follows: a player rolls two dice. If the sum of the dice is either a 2, 3, or 12, the player loses; if the sum is either a 7 or an 11, the player wins. If the outcome is anything else, the player continues to roll the dice until she rolls either the initial outcome or a 7. If the 7 comes first, the player loses, whereas if the initial outcome reoccurs before the 7 appears, the player wins. Let X be the sum of the dice with which the game is over. Find the probability mass function (pmf) of X.
For the solution, I denoted $P_n$ = $P$$($sum of dice = $n$$)$
Then $P(X = 2) = P_2$, $P(X = 3) = P_3$, $P(X = 11) = P_{11}$, $P(X = 12) = P_{12}$ since if they finish with 2, 3, 11, 12, it means that they ended at the first roll.
And for the others, I made the following formula: (when $k \neq 7$) because once they get $k$ on the first round, they should get another numbers (not 7 or k) for the next $n-2$ times and finally get a k at last.
$$
P(X = k) = \Sigma^\infty_{n = 2}P_k(1-P_k-P_7)^{n-2}P_k = \frac{P_k^2}{\frac{1}{6}+P_k}
$$
And for 7, I divided the case into two: First, the first roll got 7 (the game ended). Second, first roll wasn't 7. The probability of the first case is $\frac{6}{36}$ and the second case is as the following:
$$
\Sigma_{k \notin \{2, 3, 7, 11, 12\}} \Sigma_{n = 2}^\infty P_k(1-P_k-P_7)^{n-2}P_7 = \Sigma_{k \notin \{2, 3, 7, 11, 12\}} \frac{P_k}{1 + 6P_k}
$$
I think my answer is correct, but the sum of PMF don't give me the number 1. Is there anyone who can help me with the solution?

This looks fine.  What are your eleven $P(X=k)$? - the numbers?  Did you include $6/36$ in your final $P(X=7)$?

The sum of the two events is $P_k$. When you sum all $P_k$ you obtain $1$.

@user what do you mean..? I didn't understand it

I mean that the sum of all probabilities is equal to $1$. This was your problem, was not it?

Oh rly? I'll try it again
